# Failing to load engine in Openssl

Tags: openssl

I'm trying to test an engine to talk to an [HSM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_security_module), but it fails spectacularly:

```
$ openssl engine -t dynamic -pre ~/Downloads/engine_openhsmd.so -pre ID:openhsmd
                      -pre LIST_ADD:1 -pre LOAD -pre ADDRESS_CONN:150.162.56.205

(dynamic) Dynamic engine loading support
[Failure]: /home/boppreh/Downloads/engine_openhsmd.so
3073775292:error:260AC089:engine routines:INT_CTRL_HELPER:invalid cmd name:eng_ctrl.c:134:
3073775292:error:260AB089:engine routines:ENGINE_ctrl_cmd_string:invalid cmd name:eng_ctrl.c:316:
[Success]: ID:openhsmd
[Success]: LIST_ADD:1
[Success]: LOAD
[Failure]: ADDRESS_CONN:150.162.56.205
3073775292:error:260AC089:engine routines:INT_CTRL_HELPER:invalid cmd name:eng_ctrl.c:134:
3073775292:error:260AB089:engine routines:ENGINE_ctrl_cmd_string:invalid cmd name:eng_ctrl.c:316:
Loaded: (openhsmd) OpenHSMd engine
     [ unavailable ]
```

I can't understand a line of the output. What could be the source of the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The engine path is a parameter and must be prefixed by the parameter name `SO_PATH:`. Additionally the path must be absolute, but once you add the parameter name the resulting errors are easier to read.

```
$ openssl engine -t dynamic -pre SO_PATH:/home/boppreh/Downloads/engine_openhsmd.so
     -pre ID:openhsmd -pre LIST_ADD:1 -pre LOAD -pre ADDRESS_CONN:150.162.56.205

(dynamic) Dynamic engine loading support
[Success]: SO_PATH:/home/boppreh/Downloads/engine_openhsmd.so
[Success]: ID:openhsmd
[Success]: LIST_ADD:1
[Success]: LOAD
[Success]: ADDRESS_CONN:150.162.56.205
Loaded: (openhsmd) OpenHSMd engine
     [ available ]
```